# How to call on destroy() method without being called onPause & onStop

Tags: java, android, activity-lifecycle

I want to call `onDestroy()` method without calling other method of lifecycle apart from `onCreate()` method.

Answer (score 6):

You need to call `finish()` in your `onCreate()` method

[**`void finish ()`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#finish())

> Call this when your `activity` is done and should be closed. The `ActivityResult` is propagated back to whoever launched you via `onActivityResult()`.

Answer (score 3):

You have to invoke `finish()` in `onCreate()`